# Web Service Throwing Exception

Tags: .net, web-services, sharepoint, soap

I'm having a difficult time implementing a web service client. I'm querying a SharePoint 2010 web service using a web reference. The code below throws an exception on the line within the try block.

```
SoapService.Lists service = new SoapService.Lists();
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode query = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"Query","");
XmlNode viewFields = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"ViewFields","");
XmlNode queryOptions = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"QueryOptions","");
query.InnerXml = @"<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Vendor Name'/></IsNotNull></Where>";
viewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name='Vendor Name'/>";
queryOptions.InnerXml = @"<QueryOptions/>";

try
{
    XmlNode response = service.GetListItems("DLA-Suppliers", null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null); // exception thrown
}
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Detail);
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

Here is the exception (SoapServerException) stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at DLAUpdateSP.SoapService.Lists.GetListItems(String listName, String viewName, XmlNode query, XmlNode viewFields, String rowLimit, XmlNode queryOptions, String webID) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DLAUpdateSP\Web References\SoapService\Reference.cs:line 455
at DLAUpdateSP.Program.UpdateSuppliers(String fileLocation) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DLAUpdateSP\Program.cs:line 58
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Aside from the stack trace, the exception's properties were almost all null. I've never done SOAP before so this is really new to me. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.InnerXml = @"<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Vendor Name'/></IsNotNull></Where>";
viewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name='Vendor Name'/>";
```

The issue is your FieldRef Name. I had the same issue and solved it using the internal name which can be found in your List browser URL. Probably VendorName (without space).

Correct your code as follows

```
    SoapService.Lists service = new SoapService.Lists();
    service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode query = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"Query","");
    XmlNode viewFields = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"ViewFields","");
    XmlNode queryOptions = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"QueryOptions","");
    query.InnerXml = @"<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='VendorName'/></IsNotNull>          </Where>";
    viewFields.InnerXml = @"<FieldRef Name='VendorName'/>";
    queryOptions.InnerXml = @"<QueryOptions/>";

    try
    {
    XmlNode response = service.GetListItems("DLA-Suppliers", null, query, viewFields,  null,  queryOptions, null); // exception thrown
    }
    catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Detail);
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
```

Comment: Remember that the spaces in field names are often converted to `_x0020_`
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/787/finding-the-internal-name-and-display-name-for-a-list-column

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see more of the code to get a better idea of which methods are yours and such, but at first glance I can see that you are passing in a few `null`s into the service's `GetListItems` method. While this may be completely innocent, I'd have a look at the service's code/documentation if you can access it and see if it is expecting actual values instead of `null`.

As a side note, if you are the one who created the service, I would try to make it in a way that I wouldn't have to manually build XML queries. I would try to make a WCF service that provides methods to accomplish what you want with minimal headaches.

Comment: I didn't create the web service, this is part of the SharePoint Web Service API. I don't believe passing in nulls is a problem given that it's done that way in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Ah I see...I'm surprised MS recommends manual manipulation of XML strings just to access a service...it's just so inelegant. That said, I have no idea what is happening with your code...my only other advice is to perhaps check the log on SharePoint server if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the SharePoint servers either. If I did, I wouldn't be using a web service. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On second thoughs, you may be suffering because of the where clause. I.e. the fieldname is almost guaranteed not to work with a space. (The FieldRef Name attribute requires the Internal Name of the field)

Get a copy of [SharePoint Caml Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) this will allow you to make sure the values are correct and data will be returned.